# Best way to get Properties when they are not public / PHP

Tags: php, properties

I have a class that when I instantiate it fill the property via construct.
The goal of this class is describe a shop, so his properties will protected because they belongs only to that class.

But the problem is that sometimes I need to get some informations about that class from the properties.

**example:**

```
class Shop {

  protected $name;

  protected $typology;

  protected $owners;

  protected $closed;

  public function __construct($name,$typology,$owners,$closed)
  {
       $this->name = $name;
       $this->typology = $typology;
       $this->owners = $owners;
       $this->close = $closed;
  }

}

$shop = new Shop("Name Shop","vegetarian",2,1);

$superMarket = SupermarketFactory::getInstance($shop);
```

On the class `Supermaket` that (instantiated via Factory), need to get shop properties to work with.

There are a bunch of ways to make this work, but all solutions are a bit messy on my view point. I experimented this ways:

- Setting getters and setters - To exclude this way, having 20 properties I need 40 methods. Scripts are not efficient.
- Using `__get()` magic method, my IDE complain about getting those property via magic method. That's even true because at this point I could set it public.
- Using Reflection, It seem to be the best of the above ways, but still need too much implementation for get only properties ( I guess)

So I would like achieve the best design to get this work, have a class that has protected property but at the same time callable in a elegant way.

There is any of design pattern that helps this goal?

I may have ask already something similar on stackOverflow but I reviewed the question and proposed in a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a list of properties accessible via `__get()` and `__set()` in your class docblock using the `@property` tag that should make them visible to IDEs

See http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/phpdoc/tags/property.html and http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/PHP/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.property.pkg.html for reference and examples

Comment: Thanks it worked, so you think that the best way is keep this class with the `__get()` magic method?

Comment: I don't see any problem with having individual getters and setters either; but if you have 20 properties with getters and setters you've probably reached the point where you need to decompose your class a bit anyway.... with the exception of ORMs and similar that have properties for database structures that are dependent on the number of columns in database tables (and which tend to use __get() and __set() anyway, you shouldn't normally have that many properties in any one class

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer has been helpfull, but i would like keep the question open a bit, anyway, reading this post https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-php it keep me  away from using getters and setters

Comment: There's an overhead in using all magic methods like __get(), __set(), __isset() etc, but unless you have actually measured it to be a problem in your own situation, don't avoid magic methods where it is appropriate to use them just based on worries about performance.... use them where appropriate and only change when you can see that is gives a speed problem (ie when you're using them thousands of times in every request). For most applications, you'll have a lot more slow code than a few magic method calls